# Algorithm: how to divide grid column width ( like google-chrome )

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grid, browser

I'm building a fluid (html) grid using JavaScript. I like to use the bin-packing algorithm to order the grid-items. The grid should divide the columns by percentage or by a given amount of columns in the grid.

I`m stuck finding or creating an algorithm what can dived columns 'equally' (like the example below). Since a-lot-of browsers  handle this different (sub-pixel rendering), I like to do set the columns widths by JavaScript. I like the way Google Chrome (38.0.2125.104) divides the pixels. And hope someone can help or show me how this done. A example of how Chrome does this:

width : 100px - 3 columns (33.333333333%)
33px | 34px | 33px |

width : 100px - 8 columns (12.5%)
13px | 12px | 13px | 12px | 13px | 12px | 13px | 12px

width : 99px - 4 columns (25%)
25px | 25px | 24px | 25px

width : 99px - 8 columns (12.5%)
12px | 13px | 12px | 13px | 12px | 12px | 13px | 12px

I got as far as finding the remainder but I don`t even know if that's the way to go. I made some tests trying to recreate the above but failed hopelessly.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div> 
</div>

var x = 3; //divisor (3 columns)
var y = 100; //number (100 px)
var rem = y % x; //remainder (modulo (or bitwise))

console.log(rem); //output: 1
```

A simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dgvc268n/. To make sure to be clear about my question. I look mostly for help with the algorithm (recreate the division of items (width) like chrome), and so so much with the code of get offsetWidth or implementations like that.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo` width : 100px - 3 columns (33.333333333%)](http://jsfiddle.net/wdp1j2jd/)***
***[`jsFiddle Demo` width : 99px - 4 columns (25%)](http://jsfiddle.net/wdp1j2jd/1/)***

One approach would be to take an array of columns, and a parent grid, and then iterate through each column and through each item in each column changing widths based on the parent grid's width and remainder left over from each column fitting there.

```
function fluid(grid,columns){
 var colCount = columns.length;
 var gridWidth = grid.clientWidth;
 var colWidth = gridWidth / colCount;
 if( parseInt(colWidth,10) === colWidth ){
  for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++){
   var col = columns[i];
   for(var n = 0; n < col.length; n++){
    col[n].style.width = colWidth + "px";     
   }      
  }
 }else{
  var remainder = gridWidth - parseInt(colWidth,10) * colCount;
  var added = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++){
   var calcWidth; 
   if( i > 0 && added < remainder ){
    added++;
    calcWidth = parseInt(colWidth,10)+1 + "px";
   }else{
    calcWidth = parseInt(colWidth,10) + "px";
   }
   var col = columns[i];
   for(var n = 0; n < col.length; n++){
    col[n].style.width = calcWidth;     
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I follow the logic of your function. I still wonder though what 'logic or formula' makes that the chrome browser renders the column widths in a different order. I guess they choice these orders so the pixels difference is the least noticeable for the eye - especially with more columns (8 column example using your function http://jsfiddle.net/k70opnod). Would you have an suggestion on that?